# Sum_y = sum(y) TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have a list ,

```
y = [ 39343.0, 46205.0, 37731.0, 43525.0, 39891.0, 56642.0, 60150.0, 54445.0, 64445.0, 57189.0, 63218.0, 55794.0, 56957.0, 57081.0, 61111.0, 67938.0, 66029.0, 83088.0, 81363.0, 93940.0, 91738.0, 98273.0, 101302.0, 113812.0, 109431.0, 105582.0, 116969.0, 112635.0, 122391.0, 121872.0]
```

and I am trying to count the sum of list:

```
Sum_y = sum(y)
```

it give me error.

```
y = [ 39343.0, 46205.0, 37731.0, 43525.0, 39891.0, 56642.0, 60150.0, 54445.0, 64445.0, 57189.0, 63218.0, 55794.0, 56957.0, 57081.0, 61111.0, 67938.0, 66029.0, 83088.0, 81363.0, 93940.0, 91738.0, 98273.0, 101302.0, 113812.0, 109431.0, 105582.0, 116969.0, 112635.0, 122391.0, 121872.0]

Sum_y = sum(y)
```

Comment: What is your code, exactly?

Comment: if  you use name `sum` to keep list - `sum = [...]` - then now you can't use function `sum()` . Change name of your list

Comment: Hello! Can you please edit your post such that the code is correctly formatted and describe the error message?

Comment: When I run your code there are no errors so the problem must be somewhere else. Can you share the actual error message and the rest of your file

Comment: this is my code exectly , I am just sum up the list y = [ 39343.0, 46205.0, 37731.0, 43525.0, 39891.0, 56642.0, 60150.0, 54445.0, 64445.0, 57189.0, 63218.0, 55794.0, 56957.0, 57081.0, 61111.0, 67938.0, 66029.0, 83088.0, 81363.0, 93940.0, 91738.0, 98273.0, 101302.0, 113812.0, 109431.0, 105582.0, 116969.0, 112635.0, 122391.0, 121872.0]
Sum_y = sum(y)

Comment: @akashhardha, is [this](https://repl.it/repls/ExpertScholarlySystem) your code? Because if it is, then it works.

Comment: The error is only reproducible if you used `sum` in some other parts of your code to store a list. Try printing `sum` before `sum(y)` to check that it is still Python's `<built-in function sum>`. It's probably some `list`, resulting in your error.

Comment: ok I will try again

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a have line in your code where you have a variable called `sum` like this:

```
sum = [1,2,3]
```

and then lower down you have a list for example:

```
y = [4,5,6]
```

and then you try to find the `sum` of the values in the list:

```
sum_y = sum(y)
```

That will give you the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

because you've overwritten the default sum method with a list.

So just don't use the variable name `sum`. That goes the same for any default method or class name. You should avoid overwriting any of the default Python methods/classes.

Comment: ... and all the other [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it is not throwing any errors for me.

```
y = [ 39343.0, 46205.0, 37731.0, 43525.0, 39891.0, 56642.0, 60150.0, 54445.0, 64445.0, 57189.0, 63218.0, 55794.0, 56957.0, 57081.0, 61111.0, 67938.0, 66029.0, 83088.0, 81363.0, 93940.0, 91738.0, 98273.0, 101302.0, 113812.0, 109431.0, 105582.0, 116969.0, 112635.0, 122391.0, 121872.0]

Sum_y = sum(y)

 o/p: 2280090.0
```

For details about sum: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum